# Preventing multiple pannable table view cells being panned

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

My cells are pannable by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. My problem is, I only want a single cell to be panned at a time. To do this I've added tried a few things:

**Option 1, Using a `Bool` property for each cell:**

```
class PannableCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var controller: TableViewController? 

    var isPanning = false

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        panGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan))

        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let cells = controller?.tableView.visibleCells.filter({ $0 != self }) else { return }
        guard !cells.contains(where: { ($0 as? PannableCell)?.isPanning ?? false }) else { return }

        if recognizer.state == .began { isPanning = true }

        if recognizer.state == .changing { } //moving cell

        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { }) {
                 if $0 { self.isPanning = false } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code, only one cell at a time is able to be panned. Unfortunately there are cases (approx. 5 - 10%) where multiple cells are able to be panned. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the cell's being reused when being panned or tapped.

I know I should let the view controller handle controlling things as stated in the MVC-model. I'm not sure whether it would solve the problem mentioned before.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Could you make it like:

```
if recognizer.state == .began { self.isPanning = true }
```

I guess until you set isPanning = true the recognizer can trigger another call to your handle method that will also get through and both will end up at:

```
if recognizer.state == .began { isPanning = true }
```

I have no idea what language is this, but you must use some lock to block the thread right at the beginning of the handle method and after you check for  state. began you can release the lock, thus the conditions at the begging of the method will see there is already a cell with isPanning = true. You can make the handle thread safe, also !

Ok I read something about it, obviously there is no good synchronization in swift, but there is good enough documentation. Checked this one:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate

In your case you must add a delegate and implement:

```
optional func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

Try like this:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    panGesture.delegate = self 

    panGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan))

    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (gestureRecognizer == panGesture && (otherGestureRecognizer.view.isDescendantOfView(gestureRecognizer.view)) {
        return true
        } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it didn't solve my answer but indirectly I found a solution to fix it. Thanks!